# Interpolating a peak for two values of x - Python

Tags: python, numpy, interpolation

I want to find two values of `x` that intersect a certain value of `y` on a `x-y` plot of a resonance curve. However, as I have few data points I will need to interpolate to find these values of `x`.

The curve I am looking at can be seen below:
[image]

How do I find the two values of `x` that equal a `y` value (shown in red)?

I have tried `np.interpolate` by splitting the data into two arrays: first with `gradient(y)>0` and another with `gradient(y)<0`, however this yielded incorrect values. However, this approach is far from elegant and I seek a simple solution. Cheers in advance for any help.

Additional information:
Code used thus far:

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
from scipy import optimize

#Get data
fn = '4K_peak_hiresGhz.txt'
F_values, S_values, P_values = loadtxt(fn, unpack=True, usecols=[1, 2, 3])

#Select Frequency range of peak
lower = 4.995
upper = 5.002
F_values_2 = F_values[(F_values>lower) & (F_values<upper)]
S_values_2 = S_values[(F_values>lower) & (F_values<upper)]
P_values_2 = P_values[(F_values>lower) & (F_values<upper)]

#Calculate Q-value of selected peak
S_Peak = max(S_values_2)
print('S21 peak (dB):')
print(S_Peak)
print

F_Peak = F_values_2[S_values_2.argmax()]
print('Freq at S21 peak (GHz)')
print(F_Peak)
print

width_S = S_Peak - 3
print('S21 peak - 3dB (dB)')
print(width_S)
print

f, axarr = pl.subplots(2, sharex=False)
axarr[0].set_xlabel('Frequency (GHz)')
axarr[0].plot(F_values_2,S_values_2)
axarr[0].plot(F_values_2,S_values_2,'.')
axarr[0].set_ylabel('S21 (dB)')
axarr[0].axhline(y=width_S, linewidth='0.7', ls='dashed',color='red')
axarr[0].axhline(y=S_Peak, linewidth='1', ls='dashed', color='black')
axarr[0].axvline(x=F_Peak, linewidth='1', ls='dashed', color='black')
axarr[1].scatter(F_values_2, P_values_2)
axarr[1].set_ylabel('Phase (deg)')
axarr[1].set_xlabel('Frequency (GHz)')
pl.show()
```

Also, the data analysed in this program is found in this dpaste: http://dpaste.com/13AMJ92/

Comment: it would be great if you could post the `x, y` data that generated this plot...

Comment: Good point. Data added in a dpaste and my initial bits of code added to my question.

Comment: Take a look at the function `find_transition_times` in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112964/digitizing-an-analog-signal/15114952#15114952  You could use a variation of that function.  It finds where the curve *increases* through a threshold, but getting any intersection should be an easy modification.

Comment: You mention in a comment down the page that it should be a lorenzian fit, is this correct?

Comment: So to one of the answers which seemed completely legitimate to me you commented that you need it to be a Lorentzian fit. Perhaps you should add that to the question. Googling Lorentzian fit in python also brings you here: http://mesa.ac.nz/?page_id=1800

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `np.interp()` in this case as:

```
np.interp(width_S, S_values_2, F_values_2)
```

In your plot the `ticklabels` are different from the `thickvalues`, you can check this fact comparing:

```
print(axarr[0].get_xticks())
print([s.get_text() for s in axarr[0].get_xticklabels()])
```

The interpolated value using this formula is correct, you have to set the right tick values to see that:

```
axarr[0].set_xticklabels(map(str, axarr[0].get_xticks()))
```

Comment: Plus, I seek _two_ x values that correspond to width_S. Can interp do this?

Comment: For example, when I do that I get the following plot - using `value = np.interp(width_S, S_values_2, F_values_2)` and `axarr[0].axvline(x=value,linewidth='1', ls='dashed', color='blue')`. Plot: http://i60.tinypic.com/14o4svl.png. Blue dashed line shows the incorrect interp!

Comment: @user2992169 check the update, the problem with your plot is that the `ticklabels` are different from the `tickvalues`...

Answer (score 7):

Prepare curve data:

```
from numpy import *
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
import scipy as scipy
from scipy import optimize

#Get data
fn = '13AMJ92.txt'
F_values, S_values, P_values = loadtxt(fn, unpack=True, usecols=[1, 2, 3])

#Select Frequency range of peak
lower = 4.995
upper = 5.002
F_values_2 = F_values[(F_values>lower) & (F_values<upper)]
S_values_2 = S_values[(F_values>lower) & (F_values<upper)]

S_Peak = max(S_values_2)
F_Peak = F_values_2[S_values_2.argmax()]
width_S = S_Peak - 3
```

split at peak, and use `interp()`:

```
idx = S_values_2.argmax()
x1 = np.interp(width_S, S_values_2[:idx+1], F_values_2[:idx+1])
x2 = np.interp(width_S, S_values_2[-1:idx-1:-1], F_values_2[-1:idx-1:-1])
print x1, x2
```

the output:

```
4.99902583799 4.99954573393
```

You can also use Shapely:

```
from shapely import geometry
curve = geometry.asLineString(np.c_[F_values_2, S_values_2])
hline = geometry.LineString([(F_values_2[0], width_S), (F_values_2[-1], width_S)])
print np.asarray(curve.intersection(hline))
```

the output:

```
[[  4.99902584 -21.958     ]
 [  4.99954573 -21.958     ]]
```

If it's ok to use cubic splines, then you can use `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`:

```
from scipy import interpolate
us = interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(F_values_2, S_values_2 - width_S)
x1, x2 = us.roots()
print x1, x2
pl.plot(F_values_2, S_values_2 - width_S)
x = np.linspace(F_values_2[0], F_values_2[-1], 100)
pl.plot(x, us(x))
pl.axhline(0)
pl.plot([x1, x2], [0, 0], "o")
```

the output:

```
4.99891956723 4.99960633369
```

the plot:

[image]

Comment: This is nice but it shifts the resonance peak upwards and only finds routes at S_values_2 = 0, rather than S_Peak - 3...

Comment: Although really I should be using a Lorentzian fit!