# finding the interpolated intersection between two arrays in Python/Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, linear-interpolation

I am looking for a simple approach to finding the interpolated intersection between two Numpy arrays. I know that this is simply achieved if we have two function handles, rather than two arrays, as shown in [this](http://scipy-cookbook.readthedocs.io/items/Intersection.html) link using Scipy or using Sympy. I want to do the same, but given two arrays, specifically between the linear spline that results from connecting array entries by lines.

For example, suppose we have two arrays, `y_1` and `y_2`, both thyought of as being evaluated at `xSupport`.

```
import numpy as np
xSupport = np.array([0,1])
y_1 = np.array([0,2])
y_2 = np.array([1,0])
```

I am looking for the function that returns `1/3`, which is the x value at the intersections between these two lines. In my application the support is larger than two, so I am looking for an approach that is independent of the arrays' length.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Along the same lines as ser's answer:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([0,1])
y1 = np.array([0,2])
y2 = np.array([1,0])

def solve(f,x):
    s = np.sign(f)
    z = np.where(s == 0)[0]
    if z:
        return z
    else:
        s = s[0:-1] + s[1:]
        z = np.where(s == 0)[0]
        return z

def interp(f,x,z):
    m = (f[z+1] - f[z]) / (x[z+1] - x[z])
    return x[z] - f[z]/m

f = y1-y2
z = solve(f,x)
ans = interp(f,x,z)

print(ans)
```

The problem can be simplified by assuming that you're finding a zero, and then performing the function on the difference of the two series.  First, 'solve' finds where a sign transition occurs (implying a zero occurs somewhere in between) and then 'interp' performs a linear interpolation to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Over in [Digitizing an analog signal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112964/digitizing-an-analog-signal/15114952#15114952), I created a function called `find_transition_times` .  You could use that function by passing `y_1 - y_2` for `y` and `0` for `threshold`:

```
In [5]: xSupport = np.array([0,1])
   ...: y_1 = np.array([0,2])
   ...: y_2 = np.array([1,0])
   ...: 

In [6]: find_transition_times(xSupport, y_1 - y_2, 0)
Out[6]: array([ 0.33333333])
```